# Given x,y point, how to get window handle for a control which is NOT present on the foreground window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I know that the WindowFromPoint can be used to obtain a handle to the control if that control resides in a visible window. My requirement is to get the control details, even if the application's window is not in the foreground (it is not minimised, just that it can be behind another window). Is there a WINAPI function available which can do this for me?

If not, can someone suggest an approach as to how I can go about doing this, falling short of:
1. Enumerating all the controls in a particular background window,
2. then getting their bounds, 
3. and then comparing if those bounds contain the x,y coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function which can be used to enumerate all windows and then the [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of those functions, and the brute force approach of using them was my last resort. Though I would prefer to use EnumChildWindows instead of GetWindow :) EDIT: The GW_HWNDNEXT parameter to GetWindow looks interesting! Let me see if I can leverage that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I tried using GetWindow and passed GW_HWNDNEXT, but as the documentation suggests, I get sibling windows instead of the window directly below the topmost window. I eventually gave up and enumerated all the controls, and matched them using GetWindowRect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `WM_NCHITTEST` can help? See for example [WM_NCHITTEST is for hit-testing, and hit-testing can happen for reasons other than the mouse being over your window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/18/10131176.aspx) over at The Old New Thing.

> The `WM_NC­HIT­TEST` message doesn't mean that the mouse is in your window; it just means that somebody is asking, "If the mouse *were* in your window, what would it be doing?"

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The DefWindowProc function returns one of the values in an enumeration (which correspond to a control type) in response to a WM_NCHITTEST message. I actually need the control handle itself.